# Failed to Send error when sharing notes and pics

Tags: google-mirror-api

I have a mirror-api application i'm writing that takes notes, pictures and video from the users timeline and stores them. For some reason every note and picture I take and send to a contact i inserted through mirror has "Failed to Send" posted on the timeline card in glass. The app however still receives the timeline item. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Have you some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the timeline subscription (https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/subscriptions/insert) with "UPDATE" item included in the "operation" list. 
Mirror API will sending POST queries with the shared card info to your callbackURL endpoint. Accordingly your service should return HTTP Status 200 in response.
The endpoint should have HTTPS connection. To solve this  -  use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) if you're developing on localhost or Google's subscription proxy (just google it, i can post more than 2 links now)